# Google Chrome command line link with named tags from a vb string

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, character-encoding

I have a series of HTTP links stored in the database the have a named tag as part of the link (e.g. `http://somecompany.com/products#123332`)  which represents a product 123332 in a rather large page.

The above link works fine when using IE but doesn't work with Chrome. The `#` character gets converted to `%23` and Chrome can't find the ref. Changing the `%23` back to `#` in the browser's address field works correctly.

The link is stored in a standard VB `String` and I've tried replacing the `#` with different values via `String.Replace()`. There must be a proper way to encode this correctly, I just can't seem to find any references on the web that seem to work.

A simplified example of the call would be something like:

```
Shell(strBrowser & strLink)
```

where `strBrowser` contains all the necessary path and exe name and the `strLink` is a string similar to what I mentioned above. Also as mentioned it works fine with IE. How can I go about encoding this correctly?

Thanks.

The code

```
If oFichierAide.LienIntern = 1 Then
    strLink = " " + Chr(34) + VarGlobales.EmplacementAppl + oFichierAide.LienFichier + Chr(34)
Else
    strLink = " " + Chr(34) + oFichierAide.LienFichier + Chr(34)
End If

Try
    regBrowserKey = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("HTTP\shell\open\command", False)
    strBrowser = regBrowserKey.GetValue(Nothing).ToString().ToLower().Replace(Chr(34), "")
    strBrowser = strBrowser.Substring(0, strBrowser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4)

Finally
    If regBrowserKey IsNot Nothing Then
        regBrowserKey.Close()
    End If
End Try

If strBrowser.Length > 0 And strLink.Length > 1 Then
    Dim strCall As String = strBrowser + strLink
    Shell(strCall, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False)
    Return True
End If
```

Comment: Which version of chrome? When I type `C:/path/to/chrome.exe http://somecompany.com/products#123332` right into cmd.exe, the address bar keeps the "#". Can you show us the code where you set the `strBrowser` and `strLink` variables?

Comment: I have version 19.0.1084.52  here but not sure what version the client has.

Answer (score 1):

You can open any chrome window to any URL stored with a string variable via Visual Basic by doing:

```
Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Dim chromelocation = appdata + "\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
process.start(chromelocation + strLink)
```

Chrome should then open up and the address it goes to should be the contents of strLink.